# Foundation 6 sticky navigation producing white background for top-title-bar

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I tried to several ways to make the code below work. Now there is only one issue left and that the top-bar-title (Site Title) is having a white background when the user scrolls vertical up to the top when it should stay grey the color of the topbar. Does anybody know what is wrong?

```
  <div data-sticky-container>
    <div id="widemenu" class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%">
      <div class="top-bar-title menu-text"><a href="#">Site Title</a></div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        /ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style your widemenu div in order to keep it from being overwritten by scrolling upward. Here is your menu div with the **height** added. You could also add that style in your css file.

```
<div id="widemenu" class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%;height:50px;">
```

Good luck!